# Save the current state of a form (with properties)

Tags: javascript, forms, properties

Is there a way to save the current state of a HTML DOM Element? I mean, more than just elements and their attributes. I have a form with fieldsets and inputs that are dynamically disabled or enabled, inputs that can be added, values that are completed using dynamically loaded `<option>`s, and so forth. I want to **save the `form` object with all its *properties***. I want the user to be able to save their form. Server-side I'd like to avoid having to recreate the disabled/enabled state of fieldsets etc. based on form POST data alone.

I don't know the exact terminology, but I'd like to "export" or "serialize" the *object* and its properties which have been set using complex client-side logic (javascript). So `innerHTML` is not what I'm looking for.

Alternatively I guess there could be a script which converts all properties (values, and disabled/enabled states) into attributes first (overriding default attributes). Is there a library for this?

### Concrete example:

```
<form>
    <p>Do you want a cat?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="cat" value="Y" />Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="cat" value="N" checked />No</label>
    <fieldset class="showIfWantCat" disabled>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="striped" checked />Cat needs to be striped</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="longTail" checked />Cat needs to have a long tail</label>
        <label>Minimum tail length (cm): <input type="text" name="tailLength" value="25" class="showIfLongTail" /></label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
    // Script dynamically enables/disables fieldset(s) and inputs based on class name and current form values
</script>
```

When user submits this form, we want to save its entire state in SQL or whatever. When user wants to review/edit, we present the same form in its previous state. Recreating the form from POST data (e.g. with PHP) is too difficult. If `$_POST['striped']` is not set, does that mean that the user unchecked the box, or that its parent fieldset was disabled? To build in this logic (looking at the value of `$_POST['cat']` whether it's Y or N) would mean writing an awful lot of business logic-specific code.

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this, you'll need to write your own code to do it.

Comment: @Barmar check my code. the serializing is easy. is there any transparent way to feed a form with data back?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Yes, I knew that serialization is easy, the hard part is deserialization. "do this" referred to both directions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FormData` to serialize a form values in `localStorage` and load the data into the form on the page load. The only problem you should handle various inputs differently when loading the data into the form.

About recreating all attributes and the form's state:

**You should avoid this.**

Because this is a derived state from the form's data and all data that's loaded dynamically.
So you should write a function that set attributes of all form elements based on the current form data. You can re-use it when any data is changed afterwards. It's a very good design pattern that way you can be sure that the form's state is always in sync regardless of how the data is updated.

[The codepen is here.](https://codepen.io/silentmantra/pen/vYQgvVa)

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

const stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form-data') || '{}');

for(const name in stored){
  const elems = form.querySelectorAll(`[name="${CSS.escape(name)}"]`);
  if(!elems.length){
    continue;
  }
  if('checkbox radio'.includes(elems[0].type)){
    const elem = [...elems].filter(elem => elem.value === stored[name])[0];
    elem && (elem.checked = stored[name]);
  }else{
    elems[0].value = stored[name];
  }
}

form.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const data = new FormData(form);
  localStorage.setItem('form-data', JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data)));
});
```

```html
<form>
<input name="lname">
<input name="fname">
<div>
  <label><input checked type="radio" name="gender" value="-">Not set</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">Male</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="f">Female</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="18plus">I'm 18 years old or older</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `FormData()` does not capture which inputs and fieldsets are disabled, does it? This is the crux of my problem.